# "Hence me contacting you" vs "hence I contacted you"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

I am writing a to a business recipient and ended up with the following sentence (version 1):

> Yes, I am aware that your company is not operating this system anymore, but would be most interested in past/historical data, **hence me contacting you**.

Alternatively, I thought about changing the last part of the sentence to (version 2):

> ... hence I contacted you.

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hence%20me%2Chence%20I&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chence%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chence%20I%3B%2Cc0) seem to favor version 2, but I have the feeling I read version 1 before. [This source](https://grammarist.com/usage/hence/) seems to indicate version 1 is correct (see the second example, "*hence* means *from this source*").

Are both forms correct? Is there a preferred one in this case? Why?

Comment: No, using *me* is not standard business English. Your link does not agree with using the structure *me contacting*.

Comment: For an explanation of #1 see here: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2625/191178. Option #2 is a comma splice, I believe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is a gerund supposed to be preceded by a possessive adjective/determiner?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-adjective-determiner)

Comment: A hint:  You should do away with "hence".

Answer (score 2):

[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hence)
 gives the following for this sense of **hence**:

> that [the following] is the reason or explanation for:
>
> - *His mother was Italian, hence his name – Luca.*
> - *Peter's leaving at the end of this week – hence his anxiety to get his work finished.*
> - *The prime minister was attending the conference, hence all the extra security.*
> - *He's just got a pay rise, hence the new car.*
> - *She's just found out she failed her exams, hence her bad mood.*
> - *The firm is owned by Mark Atkins, hence the name – MA Advertising.*

Note that hence is followed in every example by a noun phrase, after a comma or dash depending on the amount of dramatic emphasis (vs smooth flow of the text)  desired.

Here is an example from [another thread on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198772/is-there-a-proper-way-of-talking-about-a-negative-privilege) showing an ing-form string following [not directly] *hence*:

- *The video is terrible, hence my writing about it*.

The idiomatic version would here be ... *hence my contacting you* (though *hence* can also be used with the meaning *therefore*, allowing ... *– hence/therefore I contacted you*). But this would sound somewhat less professional.

Comment: I agree with its use with noun phrases rather than an independent clause sounds more correct. Do you know if there's any authoritative reference that mentions this? I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: [Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/usage/hence/) supplies examples  with 'hence' interchangeable with 'therefore': • It’s that India has an airline that is run by politicians and hence can be milked by various interest groups. [Wall Street Journal]

• The Orthodox Church is surely a form of organised religion; hence his real quarrel is not so much with religion per se, any more than with atheism per se. [Financial Times]. ACC-ing constructions are usually found after certain verbs (I didn't like him singing) or prepositions (I just wanted to leave after _them_ singing!)

Comment: But the usage in this question is consistent with 'hence' meaning 'from this source' in the same Grammarist page.

Comment: Really? "Alternatively, I thought about changing the last part of the sentence to (version 2):

... hence I contacted you."

Comment: Both sound awkward to me. The gerund form sounds more grammatically correct but too academic / pedantic. The other form sounds like it is a non-native English speaker talking. (either that or the use of "hence" + clause is something that works better in other dialects than American English. I've heard it with my coworkers from India.) I personally wouldn't use "hence" at all in the OP's context.

Comment: You said "But the usage in this question is consistent with 'hence' meaning 'from this source' in the same Grammarist page." I disagreed, showing OP considers both usages. Now you've changed the subject.

Comment: Hence me contacting you?  No.  It is 'Hence, I contacted you.'   'Me' is I's form as an object. Can we say, Hence them contacting you?

Comment: @RamPillai look at [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund)

Comment: @JasonS: Does it need a reference? Besides, Wiki's contents are open to editing. Can we say, "Hence them contacting you"? If you say YES, then I will unlearn, and start relearning.

Comment: "Hence their contacting you", "Hence my contacting you" are grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could also avoid "hence", which is better used in literary or journalistic works. Some alternatives:

> Yes, I am aware that your company is not operating this system anymore, but would be most interested in past/historical data, so I contacted you.

or

> Yes, I am aware that your company is not operating this system anymore, but would be most interested in past/historical data, which is why I contacted you.

To my US English ear, the word "hence" sounds archaic/awkward if not used with a noun phrase as in [Merriam-Webster's website](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hence)

> Panforte—a cross between a cake and a candy—is a classic Italian Christmas treat. It's a very dense, rich confection loaded with nuts, dried fruit, and spices (hence its name, which means "strong bread").

> In the past, the playoffs lasted five rounds, but the MHSAA is doubling the size of the playoffs, hence the possible need for an extra week.

I don't have an authoritative source for this preference (noun phrase rather than clause) but it's an anecdotal assessment based on what I've read over the years.